# Como puedo solucionar este error de AndroidStudio al actualizar gradle

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He actualizado AndroidStudio a la version del 2022 y actualice tambien el Gradle a la version 8.3.0 desde las actualizaciones solo me arroja el siguiente error y no he podido hacer nada.

Gracias de antemano.